# Parse powered by Bitnami for Android (friends list)

Tags: java, android, parsing, server, bitnami

So I have written an on click method that takes in text from a user (a friend's name) then checks to see if that user exists on the database and if you are already friends with that user. If the user exists and isn't already your friend, I want it to add them to your friends list, which is an array on the Parse backend. The checks seem to be working, and "frank" is added to the list on the device however the list isn't being updated or saved on the server and I can't work out why, I've checked variable and database names for error and I cant find any. I'm testing logged in as "bill". Please find method and screenshot of database below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Parse bitnami database here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5y5Or.png)

```
   public void addFriend(View view){

    final EditText mText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo("username", mText.getText().toString());

    query.countInBackground(new CountCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(int count, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                if(count==0){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Doesn't Exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if  (ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("friendsList").contains(mText.getText().toString()))
                {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User is already a friend", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}

               else
                {
                    ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("friendsList").add(mText.getText().toString());
                    ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();
                }
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: you are using the same `mText.getText().toString()` everywhere, so I don't see how you want to compare your friend's name

Comment: @njzk2 This method queries the Users data base for the name entered by the user and if it is found it will count how many there are this is assigned to the int, count, if count is ever 0, then that user wasn't found on the data base, so doesn't exist. The 2nd time it is used, it queries the data base again to check if the user is already on your friends list (so a friend can only be added once) if both these checks are met (The user exists in the users data base, and the user's friendsList doesn't already contain the username you are adding) then mText will be added to your friends list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used Parse much myself, but from the API documents here: http://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#arrays

It looks like what is happening is you are using the `.add()` method from `List<>`, but it seems you need to use the Parse's specific `.add()` method on the `ParseObject`.

Try changing this line:

```
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("friendsList").add(mText.getText().toString());
```

to

```
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().add("friendsList", mText.getText().toString());
```